# how to read this firestore array to recyclerview android?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

my code example 1:

```
db.collection("UserHotel").document("hotelDetails").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                        if (document.exists()) {

                            List<AllRestauItem> trans = document.toObject(HotelDetail.class).transactions;

                            List<String> amountArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for(AllRestauItem transaction : trans) {
                                String amount = transaction.getHotelName();
                                amountArrayList.add(amount);
                            }

                            Log.d("ARRAY", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + trans.toString());

                            AllRestauAdp allRestauAdp = new AllRestauAdp(view.getContext(), amountArrayList);
                            recyclerRestorent.setAdapter(allRestauAdp);


                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "No such document");
                        }

                    }else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

my code example 2:

```
ArrayList<HotelDetail> viewOrderModelList = new ArrayList<HotelDetail>();
    db.collection("UserHotel").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                for (DocumentSnapshot docSnap : list) {
                    HotelDetail orderModel = docSnap.toObject(HotelDetail.class);
                    viewOrderModelList.add(orderModel);
                    AllRestauAdp allRestauAdp = new AllRestauAdp(view.getContext(), viewOrderModelList);
                    recyclerRestorent.setAdapter(allRestauAdp);
                }
                //viewOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

i try the above two examples and tried more but can't fetch details in recyclerview.

Comment: Show us the `AllRestauItem` and `HotelDetail` classes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `AllRestauAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();` below recyclerRestorent.setAdapter(allRestauAdp);
2. Make sure you set the layout manager of your recyclerview like this: `recyclerRestorent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));`

Comment: yes, i tried once again but not working.. kindly give me another suggestion